# Is there a static way to get the current HttpServletRequest in Spring

Tags: spring, servlets, request

I am using Spring annotations, I can pass the `HttpRequestContext` from the Controller to the Service.

I am looking for a static way or any better solution than passing `RequestContext` around.

Answer (score 138):

If you are using spring you can do the following:

```
public static HttpServletRequest getCurrentHttpRequest(){
    RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
    if (requestAttributes instanceof ServletRequestAttributes) {
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes)requestAttributes).getRequest();
        return request;
    }
    logger.debug("Not called in the context of an HTTP request");
    return null;
}
```

Comment: tie this as a bean? How'd using 'autowired' do here, instead of a static method?

Comment: Every few years I come back to this answer and reuse this snippet.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Remember to declare `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` as a listener in your `web.xml` for this to work.

Answer (score 37):

Or the java8 way

```
public static Optional<HttpServletRequest> getCurrentHttpRequest() {
    return Optional.ofNullable(RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())
        .filter(ServletRequestAttributes.class::isInstance)
        .map(ServletRequestAttributes.class::cast)
        .map(ServletRequestAttributes::getRequest);
}
```

Comment: You can replace the filter with `ServletRequestAttributes::isInstance`

Comment: And you then can add a map to `ServletRequestAttributes::cast` after the filter to avoid the cast on the subsequent map.

Comment: Neither of those methods exist in Java.

Comment: They're members of `Class`, so they should be `ServletRequestAttributes.class::isInstance` and `ServletRequestAttributes.class::cast`.

Answer (score 14):

I know, it is already answer. I would like to mark as new update. we can inject `HttpServletRequest` by using `@Autowired`. It is working fine at `springboot`.

```
@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;
```

Answer (score 7):

For reference, this would be the Kotlin way:

```
    val currentRequest: HttpServletRequest?
        get() = (RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() as? ServletRequestAttributes)?.request
```

Answer (score 4):

In response to @andrebrait comments above "Or the Java 8 way", the methods are present on the `ServletRequestAttributes.class`

```java
    public static Optional<HttpServletRequest> getCurrentHttpRequest() {
        return
            Optional.ofNullable(
                RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()
            )
            .filter(ServletRequestAttributes.class::isInstance)
            .map(ServletRequestAttributes.class::cast)
            .map(ServletRequestAttributes::getRequest);
    }
```

Comment: Does `isInstance` still work with subclasses?

Comment: No it does not. You should use `isAssignableFrom`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `HttpServletRequest` as a parameter in controller handler method. Like this:

```
@GetMapping("/hello")
public String hello(HttpServletRequest request) {
    //...
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

List of supported controller method arguments and return types can be found here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-methods

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```java
HttpServletRequest request = 
    ((ServletRequestAttributes) Objects.requireNonNull(
        RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()))
    .getRequest();
```