# Code equivalent from JSF to Spring Boot or Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsf, request-headers

I am building an application in Spring Boot and Thymeleaf that is already built in JSF (Java Server Faces). I have a part of the app in JSF that takes a values from the header.
This is the code:

```
operator = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
        .getRequestHeaderMap().get("user");
```

I would like to do the same in Spring Boot. I have already tried with `@RequestHeader("user")` in the Controller but I get an error saying that it cannot find this header values. Can someone translate the code from JSF to Spring Boot code or something in Java that will work ? Thanks

Comment: you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60103748/get-request-header-in-spring-boot ?

Comment: These are two different frameworks.. you really ought to learn the framework you are going to use rather than 'translate' line by line...